# How to input periods in Excel

Tags: excel, time

I have the table below:

```
╭───╥────────────┬────────────────╮
│   ║     A      │        B        │
╞═══╬════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1 ║ Jack       │ 1 year 6 months │
│ 2 ║ Emily      │ 6 months        │
│ 3 ║ Carl       │ 2 years 3 months│
│ 4 ║            │                 │
│ 5 ║ Team avg:  │ 1 years 5 months│
└───╨────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

I would like to get the time span averge from column B. Something like 1.42 years or 1 year 5 months.

Is there a way to input time periods in Excel in terms of years and months and days? I could not figure out how to use dates format for this case. 
I would prefer a non-macro solution if possible.

Ant ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the various Text functions along with `FIND` to extract the years and months; then just add the results.  The Date Formatting has nothing to do with this, since the time spans are all text strings

Comment: Thanks for the advice @RonRosenfeld. I could change column B with numbers if needed (as when we enter dates) but I don't know if there is any particular format for periods.

Comment: No there is no preset format for periods.  You could use your own by, for example, having the years represented by the Integer part of a decimal number, and the months by the decimal part.  Then, by using `INT`, `MOD`, and/or `DOLLARFR` you could switch back and forth between a Year.Month format, and the decimal format required for computations.

Comment: Wow, that's a good idea @RonRosenfeld.  Do you think I could define a custom format for a number like 2.11 be written as: 2 years 11 months ?

Comment: I think the closest you could come with formatting would look like `1 hour .05 months`  You could construct a text string that mimics the results you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since you wrote you could enter the numbers differently, and want to do it in a single column, you could for example, enter your data as `y.mm`, and then use the **array** formula below to present a human readable output.

Be sure to retain a leading zero for single digit months, as shown in the screen shot below.

```
=TEXT(INT(DOLLARFR(AVERAGE(INT(myRange)*12+MOD(myRange,1)*100)/12,12)),"[=1]0 ""year "";0"" years """) & TEXT(INT(MOD(DOLLARFR(AVERAGE(INT(myRange)*12+MOD(myRange,1)*100)/12,12),1)*100), "[=1]0"" month"";0"" months""")
```

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

[image]

If you want the output in the same format as the entries, you can use the much simpler formula (also entered as an array formula)

```
=DOLLARFR(AVERAGE(INT(myRange)*12+MOD(myRange,1)*100)/12,12
```

And, if you don't mind having a `dot` in the displayed data, and plural months/years even if months/years are one (1), you can custom format it as suggested by @RaulDurand:

```
0" years". 0 "months ";;
```

If you are going to add days into the mix, you can use a similar algorithm.  I did not provide one because, although years contain a fixed number of months, both contain a variable number of days and you will need to decide how you are going to treat that situation.  A VBA UDF would be much simpler to construct.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother looking for an intensely programmed solution: you only seem to have 4 data rows? I'd just type new data in instead

We don't to time spans in excel, but we can denote a time span by a start date and an end date. Some time spans may be dynamic, dependent on the current time

If you have 2 dates you can do simple math: later_date - earlier_date

Excel will return a result in days and fractions of a day, so for example 2000-02-01 18:00 minus 2000-01-01 00:00 will give an answer of 31.75 - it's a time span of 31.75 days

You can format 31.75 as days and hours and excel will represent it as eg 31 days 18 hours 0 minutes, but you should appreciate that that is a formatting of a numeric value of 31.75 - get used to working with and thinking of spans of time as a decimal number of days

You can add these up, average them etc

You can add a number amount to a date to advance the date by that number of days

Comment: Thanks @CaiusJard for the advice. Actually will have many worksheets with hundreds of rows.

Comment: It might be best then to write a vba macro. The problem you've essentially got though, is for data like "8 months 4 days" there isn't a direct mapping between months and days. A month varies between 28 and 31 days long so it's somewhat meaningless to use in a timespan unless you know the start date. If you're not bothered about accuracy, I'd estimate a month as 365.25/12 days long

Answer (score 0):

Just use three columns. Column B is Years. Column C is Months. Column D is the sum of B and a twelfth of C.  So, D2 would be `=B2 + C2/12`.

```
╭───╥────────────┬───┬────┬──────────────╮
│   ║     A      | B |  C | D            │
╞═══╬════════════╪═══╪════╪══════════════╡
│ 1 ║ Jack       │ 1 |  6 | = B1 + C1/12 │
│ 2 ║ Emily      │ 0 |  6 | = B2 + C2/12 │
│ 3 ║ Carl       │ 2 |  3 | = B3 + C3/12 │
│ 4 ║            │   |    |              │
│ 5 ║ Team avg:  │ * | ** | = AVG(D1:D3) │
└───╨────────────┴───┴────┴──────────────┘
```

<sup>*</sup>  B5 can be `INT(D5)` to give years
<sup>**</sup> C5 can be `(D5 - INT(D5)) * 12` to give months

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. Actually column B is part of a Table and I would not like to have two columns (with different headings) for one information.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @RonRosenfeld comments I managed to use numbers. In this case the time spans on column B are written as:

```
╭───╥────────────┬─────────────────╮
│   ║     A      │        B        │
╞═══╬════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1 ║ Jack       │            1.06 │
│ 2 ║ Emily      │            0.06 │
│ 3 ║ Carl       │            2.03 │
│ 4 ║            │                 │
│ 5 ║ Team avg:  │                 │
└───╨────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

and using the following custom format

```
0" years". 00 "months ";;
```

it becomes:

```
╭───╥────────────┬───────────────────╮
│   ║     A      │        B          │
╞═══╬════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1 ║ Jack       │ 1 years. 06 months│
│ 2 ║ Emily      │ 0 years. 06 months│
│ 3 ║ Carl       │ 2 years. 03 months│
│ 4 ║            │                   │
│ 5 ║ Team avg:  │ 1.42 years        │
└───╨────────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Then, the average time span is calculated as:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(INT(B1:B3))+SUMPRODUCT(MOD(B1:B3,1))/0.12)/COUNT(B1:B3)
```

Also, custom formatting is used in the result.